# Hidden video on iPhone

Tags: photos, video, settings, iphone

I recorded a video and cannot find it on my iPhone 6. I know it's there because when I go to settings / general / about, I see that I have one video on my phone, but it does not show in photos. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that it could only be in one of two places (and perhaps a third in a stretch) if you recorded it with the built in camera app.

- Photos -> Albums -> Videos (or Slo-mo)
- Photos -> Albums -> Recently Deleted

As I'm sure you are aware, you can also see videos under "Photos" (left most tab), or under Albums -> Camera Roll. I suspect that you checked there, though.

If you tap and hold on a video, you can choose "hide". That will hide it from places *other than* under Albums so the first option above should still work even if you have inadvertently hidden the video.

There is also an extremely remote chance that it is in the Videos app. But, you'd have to have to specifically put it there using iTunes as a go-between, so again, it is *highly* unlikely.

By the way, my phone says that I have 119 videos and the camera app's videos album shows 119.

Comment: I recorded it with the iPhone and it's not in any of the places you mention. One thing though. I remember after recording, I picked up my phone and it made a noise like it was out of storage. I only have like 1 gb of storage left.

Comment: Could you record another video briefly and see where that goes?

Comment: Yes I did that too. That video shows in photos. And when I navigate to "about" thru settings, under "video" it says I have 2 videos. But I can only see one of them. Weird.

Comment: Have you tried hard-rebooting your phone (hold down power + home buttons until the Apple logo appears)?

Comment: I just tried that, no luck. I think the video is in the phones memory somehow and did not save because storage was too low.